# How to configure JMS container factory to retry with backoff and not retry MessageConversionException

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-jms, spring-amqp

I'm having two problems while using JMS:

1. I created an instance of `ExponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries` and added to my `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` in the method `.setBackOff` but it doesnt seem to work, actually it dont do anything. When I provoke an exception on the listener it just retry for 10 times with 1 second between retries. I did something similar to the container listener of spring-kafka and was expecting the same results but it dont seem to be the case.
2. I'm using a json `MessageConverter` for the producer (`.convertAndSend`) and the the consumer but I want to catch the scenario if a invalid value is put on the queue and not retry. I believed that implementing a `ErrorHandler` and not throw the exception it would prevent the retry (with spring-kafka we can 'tell" the container what to retry and not) but its not the case. I want to know if this is even possible?

**I'll leave some snippets of the code that iam using:**

```
@Bean
fun jmsListenerContainerFactory(
    connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory,
    configurer: DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer
): JmsListenerContainerFactory<*> {
    val factory = DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory()

    // do not stop the retry
    factory.setErrorHandler(ContainerFactoryErrorHandler())

    val retryConfig = ExponentialBackOffWithMaxRetries(5).apply {
        initialInterval = 1000
        maxInterval = 10000
        multiplier = 1.5
    }

    //dont do anything, retry 10 times
    factory.setBackOff(retryConfig)

    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory)
    return factory
}

@Bean
fun jacksonJmsMessageConverter(objectMapper: ObjectMapper): MessageConverter {
    val converter = MappingJackson2MessageConverter()
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT)
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type")
    converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper)
    return converter
}
```

```
class ContainerFactoryErrorHandler : ErrorHandler {

    override fun handleError(t: Throwable) {
        when {
            t.cause is MessageConversionException -> {
                // log message and dont do nothing
            }

            else -> {
                // is a retriable exception and should throw so the container can retry
                throw t
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
@JmsListener(
    destination = "queue-1",
    containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory",
    id = "my-queue-listener",
)
fun listen(message: RemoveMe.TesteProducerData) {
    println("Read message = $message")
    throw RuntimeException("deu um erro qualquer!")
}
```

- **USING SPRING BOOT 3**
- **USING ActiveMQ Artemis and Azure Service Bus**
- **Kotlin as programming language**

Dependencies:

```
implementation("com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter")
implementation("com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus-jms")
implementation("com.azure.spring:spring-messaging-azure-servicebus")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-artemis")
```